# Can I add all files of a certain type (.php) to git recursively in a single command?

Tags: git

I am trying to add all *.php* files of a folder to my git at the same time including *.php* files in subdirectories.

This is the problem:

```
- Root/
------>Index.php
------->Dir1/
--------------->Anotherscript.php
------->Dir2/
---------------->Morephpcodes.php
```

So when placed in the root folder I would like to add all of my php code to Git

I have tried:

```
git add *.php
```

while placed at root, but this would only add *index.php*

I am wondering if there is no way of simply doing:

```
git add -R *.php
```

and this would add all php files in my website to git?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: There might be a more efficient way, but the inelegant one is a glob: `git add **/*.php`. (If `git add '**/*.php'` works, it’s better.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This only goes one level deep root/dir1/ and would not got to the second level : root/dir1/dir2/

Comment: That’s incorrect. It’s a recursive glob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use find and xargs:

```sh
find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs --null git add
```

`find` will list all files ending in `.php`, and `xargs` will create a `git add` command line with all those files.